# Background Cancle Event Form Closing Error

Tags: vb.net, background

I have a background event that is consistently withdraws data. When I close the form background event doesn't cancel for some reason. If I enable a message in between it does...... I tried to put a time pause, REFRESH, and both. But its only works properly after the message box. I don't really understand why, since button it self to cancel works fine when form is not close. ERROR "Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'Form1'." Somehow it doesn't see "False" on closing.
Thanks!

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing   
    RED(False)
    'Some other functions - WORK OK     
End Sub

Private Sub RED(ByVal reads As Boolean)
    bck.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    If reads = True Then
        bck.RunWorkerAsync()
    ElseIf reads = False Then
        bck.CancelAsync()
        bck.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub bck_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bck.DoWork
    Do
        If bck.CancellationPending = True Then --- DOESN'T look like see this without Message BOX
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Me.Invoke(Sub()
                     'EVENT HERE WERE I AM GETTING AN ERROR --- HOWEVER, Works as a button when called on RED(False) and Works if I put a message BOX
                  End Sub)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear to be a matter of timing, as is often the case with multiple threads. What I would suggest is that, if the form is closed when the background task is in progress, you cancel the background task and then cancel the close. You can then close again when the background task has completed, e.g.

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Do
        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
            'Cancel the background work.
            Exit Do
        End If

        'Do the background work.
        '...
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    'Close the form.
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
        'Cancel the background task.
        BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()

        'Do not close the form this time.
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

If you won't always want to close the form when the background task completes then you can indicate that to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler by, for instance, setting `e.Result` in the `DoWork` event handler and then testing it in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler, e.g.

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    e.Result = False

    Do
        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
            e.Result = True

            'Cancel the background work.
            Exit Do
        End If

        'Do the background work.
        '...
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If CBool(e.Result) Then
        'Close the form.
        Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank for your help! I have previously tried to use "busy" as well but it still didn't work. I kinda suspect that it was an Invoke method because if I am not wrong it ties to the From. Funny though when applying time delays in certain areas occasionally it would work but not always .... So I went and changed to what probably some would say a "proper way"  PROGRESS REPORT even though I see nothing wrong with using invoke. Regards, long story short Using Progress Report fixed my issue, again thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Use PROGRESS REPORT instead of Invoke.

```
 Private Sub bck_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bck.DoWork
        Do
            If bck.CancellationPending = True Then 
                Exit Sub
            End If
            bck.ReportProgress("WHATEVER YOU CAPTURING/VALUES UPDATE")
        Loop
    End Sub
Private Sub bck_dProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bck.ProgressChanged

               YOUR DISPLAY = ("WHATEVER YOU CAPTURING/VALUES UPDATE")


    End Sub
```